# Don't know how to add and divide cells and output in a different cell with vba

Tags: vba, excel

Getting error Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

I am trying to write a vba solution in excel and don't seem to know what I am doing wrong and I have tried to look up solutions but I just keep getting errors. Below is my code, excel is giving me an error with the second last line that starts with Range, but I don't know why. As you can see with that formula, what I am trying to do is add up the values of some cells and divide by another cell then output the result in another cell, but I guess I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 19 To 49

If Cells(i, 26) > 499999 Then
    Cells(3, 27) = 499999
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 499999 Then
    Cells(3, 27) = Cells(i, 26)
End If

If Cells(3, 27) < 499999 Then
     Cells(5, 27) = 0
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 999999 Then
    Cells(4, 27) = 500000
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 999999 Then
    Cells(4, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 499999
End If

If Cells(4, 27) = 0 Then
     Cells(5, 27) = 0
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 1999999 Then
    Cells(5, 27) = 1000000
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 1999999 Then
    Cells(5, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 999999
End If

If Cells(5, 27) = 0 Then
     Cells(6, 27) = 0
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) > 4999999 Then
     Cells(6, 27) = 3000000
ElseIf Cells(i, 26) < 4999999 Then
    Cells(6, 27) = Cells(i, 26) - 1999999
End If

If Cells(6, 27) = 3000000 Then
     Cells(7, 27) = Cells(3, i) - 4999999
ElseIf Cells(6, 27) < 3000000 Then
     Cells(7, 27) = 0
End If

Range(i, 30).Value = (Cells(3, 28) + Cells(4, 28) + Cells(5, 28) + Cells(6, 28) + Cells(7, 28)) / Cells(i, 26)

Next i
```

Comment: add .Value to the Cells. So Cells(3, 28).Value + etc

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Change `Range(i, 30).Value` to `Cells(30,i).value`  Edit, the issue is that Range wants a letter column while cells will use a number or a letter.

Comment: this worked thanks!!! Now unfortunately I have another error, my if statements don't output values as they are supposed to

Answer (score 0):

Try Range(Cells(i,30)).value at your last line.

Comment: That won't work, Range with a single Cells will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The code "Range(i, 30).Value" is the problem
A range is more than one cell.  Oligg was on the right path with his answer, however, Range cannot take only one cell as an argument.

```
 Range(Cells(i,30),Cells(i,30)).value
```

should work for you.   I would have just commented on Oliggs answer, but unfortunately, I lack the reputation to do that being fairly new here.